# Passing value from Parent to Child in Reactjs using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, react-props

I am trying to pass `theExpert.email` value to another child component whenever i click on `send questions` button.

This is the constructor of the Parent class

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
         textbox: '',
         category: '',
         exp: '',
         hide: false
        };
        this.hideButton = this.hideButton.bind(this);
}
```

The follow function hides the button once it is clicked and saves the value of the `theExpert.email` in `exp`, (`value` is passed correctly since `console.log` prints it)

```
hideButton (value) {
    this.setState({ hide: true });
    this.setState({
      exp: value
    });
    console.log(value)
}
```

And here is the button that once I click on it it passes the value to `hideButton`

```
<div>
  {!this.state.hide ? (
    <button onClick={() => this.hideButton(theExpert.email)}>Ask Me!</button>
  ) : null}  
</div>
```

Now what i want to do is once i click on `Send Questions` button i get redirected to the child component `Questions.js` and pass the value of `theExpert.email` to that component 
The button `Send Questions`:

```
 <div>
        <p>
  {(this.state.hide) && (
    <Link to="/questions">
      <button 
        style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }} 
      >
        Send Question
      </button>
    </Link>
  )}
</p>

            </div>
```

How can i retrieve `value` in the child class to create a post request using it

Comment: one option is to pass it as url param like this `"/questions?value=" this.state.exp` if you want to set it props you would have to add the "child" in render() method and then pass it like this `<Question value={this.state.exp} />`

Comment: You may create another component (SendQuestion). then send as a props.

Comment: in `hideButton()` call `setState()` once with 1 object, not twice in succession

Comment: @MotiKorets whenever i try to do `<Questions value={this.state.exp} />`  i get the following error `index.js:2177 ReferenceError: Questions is not defined
   `

Comment: Of course you need to import it first.

Comment: @MotiKorets I am still new to reactJS so could you please clarify which component should i import? Parent into child or vice versa ?

Comment: @Ikram-Ud-Daula how can i do that

Comment: what is your correct console.log value in hideButton function?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue us due to react being lazy. Basically you are just setting hide to true and re-rendering your component and all of its children but never setting exp the expected value.

So instead of

```
hideButton (value) {
    this.setState({ hide: true });
    this.setState({
      exp: value
    });
    console.log(value)
}
```

try

```
hideButton (value) {
    this.setState(prevState=>{ 
    prevState= {
      ...prevState
      hide: true ,
      exp: value
    }
    return prevState
    });
}
```

Comment: how can i then pass `exp` to the child class without rendering it in the parent class ?